# How to print a single Key-Value pair in a HashMap in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, input, maps, output

Is it possible to do so? If yes, what is the required syntax/method?

I tried it by using,

`System.out.println(key+"="+HM.get(key));`

but it prints it in this format,

key= value

whereas, I need

key=value

(Due to outputting format in HackerRank)

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()) 
{
  String s=sc.nextLine();
  if(a.containsKey(s))
  {
      System.out.println(s+"="+a.get(s));
  }
  else
  System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

EDIT 1:
I saw the solution given, the person used the following code,

```
   while(scan.hasNext()){
            String s = scan.next();
            Integer phoneNumber = phoneBook.get(s);
            System.out.println(
                (phoneNumber != null) 
                ? s + "=" + phoneNumber 
                : "Not found"
            );
        }
```

Now, why does this not have white space in the answer?

The only visible change I see is that this person used an object instead of primitive data type.

Also,this person used int instead of string in accepting the phone number, I initially did the same but it gave me an InputMismatchException .

Comment: So all you really want to do is to remove the whitespace between `=` and `value`? It's probably some padding on the value, just use `.trim()` on it.

Comment: If @Amongalen is right about the extra whitespace I would check the code where I add values to the HashMap and remove any extra whitespace before the value is added.

Comment: I tried that, i don't know why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is no avalilable method in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html to get Entity from map if there is any key or value available. Try below code if it help :

```
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
   Object value = map.get(key);
 System.out.println("Key : " + key +" value :"+ value);
 }
```

Comment: I don't see any real difference between your code and the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `entrySet()` (see [entrySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--)) to iterate over your map.

You will then have access to a [Map Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) which contains the methods `getValue()` and `getKey()` to retreive both the value and the key of your mapped object.

`entrySet()` returns a `Set`, and `Set` extends `Collection`, which offers the `stream()` method, so you can use stream to loop over and process your entrySet :

```java
map
    .entrySet() // get a Set of Entries of your map
    .stream() // get Set as Stream
    .forEach( // loop over Set
        entry -> // lambda as looping over set entries implicitly returns an Entry
            System.out.println(
                entry.getKey() // get the key
                + "="
                + entry.getValue() // get the value
    );
```

If needed, you can add `.filter()` to process only elements that matches your conditions in your Stream.

**Working example** [here](https://tio.run/##ZU89T8MwEJ2TX3HK5CitRed@TCCBoFNEF8RwtG7q1HEi@xIUofz2cE4DAyz38d7de3cldrgsT9dx1FVTO4KSAdmSNvIR/WWPzTr@x0xo3LQfRh/haNB72KO28BVHM@gJiVNX6xNUTImcnLbF2zugK3waJiNW2dzgBdzyDqqeUdiCVZ8w@/@dEbftqHG6Q1I/Vmdt0YCpbQFeOY3moJzXtX19ume91cs67EyL0bl2ILQl0IGBNecNrO5CkWWzOuu3JJKr6pNMLyDp0LSKy3TSiYZ4DkPop6ulsuT6XJFIpSensOKCrR7weBFhfOJhuYO896QqWbck@QlLxoqJk4WiZ9Xzgxkk24TjL3wI9iJNWSdcMMTDOH4D)

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            {
                for (int i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                    put("key"+i, "value"+i);
                }
            }
        };
        myMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(
            entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue())
        );
    }
}
```

Output :

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key5=value5
key6=value6
key3=value3
key4=value4
key9=value9
key7=value7
key8=value8
```